# Storing a session array into variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, multidimensional-array, session-variables

I have the session `$_SESSION['cart_array']` which stores data from my shopping cart, and once var_dumped looks like

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>array(3){
     ["item_id"]=>string(1) "6"
     ["quantity"]=>int(1)
     ["price"]=>string(5) "10.99"
   }
  [1]=>array(3) {
    ["item_id"]=>string(1) "7"
    ["quantity"]=>int(1)
    ["price"]=>string(4) "1.99"
   }
}
```

I think I need to store each column in a variable to be able to parse it to my function then Mysql query. How is this done?

Comment: Er... The `$_SESSION` array *is* a variable, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean storing the session data into your database?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ok so if I only needed to parse item_id from this array to my function, how is this done?

Comment: I'm still not sure I get what this question is about. Do you mean that you know how to *write* arrays but not how to *read* from them?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario How would I print_r just the price or item_id from that array?

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` is an array.
Run an [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
echo $_SESSION['cart_array']['0']['item_id'];
```

EDIT:

```
$product_id = $_SESSION['cart_array']['0']['item_id'];
$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactionDetails (Order_ID, Product_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES('{$orderId}', '{$product_id}', '{}', '{}')");
```

Comment: So if I wanted to put price into a mysql statement such as $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactionDetails` (Order_ID, Product_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES('{$orderId}', '{}', '{}', '{}')"); What would I put in the brackets?